# "null pointer" error while trying to manipulate string

Tags: c, string

I am developing a simple program in C to crack a hashed input, however I am not able to detect if the input is valid or not. Basically I just want to detect if the string the user inputted is valid or not before cracking the hash. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isHashValid(char *string);

int main(void){
  char *userInput = NULL;

  printf("enter hash key: ");
  scanf("%s\n", userInput);
  isHashValid(userInput);

  return 0;
}

bool isHashValid(char *string){
  int size = strlen(string);

  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    if(string[i] == ' '){
      printf("space detected\n");
      return false;
    }
  }

  printf("hash is valid!\n");
  return true;
}
```

This is the full error message:

```
 runtime error: null pointer passed as argument 1, which is declared to never be null
/usr/include/string.h:385:33: note: nonnull attribute specified here
UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
==819==ERROR: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x7f0de173e5a1 bp 0x7ffdc9ea3440 sp 0x7ffdc9ea33c8 T819)
==819==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==819==Hint: address points to the zero page.
    #0 0x7f0de173e5a0  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x18e5a0)
    #1 0x427fd8  (/home/ubuntu/crack+0x427fd8)
    #2 0x427f8b  (/home/ubuntu/crack+0x427f8b)
    #3 0x7f0de15d1b96  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)
    #4 0x402af9  (/home/ubuntu/crack+0x402af9)

UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer can not provide additional info.
==819==ABORTING
```

Comment: `scanf` doesn't perform `malloc`, so essentially you're scanning to a `NULL`  pointer and then trying to process it

Comment: char *userinput only creates a pointer, but not any space for the string. Try char userinput[100]; this will set space for 100 chars. I hope that helps.

Comment: @42LeapsOfFaith     forgot about that! thanks! just a question, if I know the user will input less than 100 characters, using userinput[100] will allocate unnecessary memory or C only uses the characters the user input?

Comment: @levengli that's true, thanks. is there a way I can use malloc but without knowing how many characters the user will input? or should I just "guess"?

Comment: Either guess, or read it in one character at a time. Keeping in mind that building a string that way is *extremely* inefficient, I'd go with the guessing method

Comment: `%s\n` as scanf format is nonsense. You want `%s`. Also it looks like you're using a C++ compiler to compile your "C" code

Comment: A string input with %s cannot have spaces either

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually allocating memory to userImput. As it is a String, you need to either use malloc, or do 
`char userInput[50]`
in order to allocate some space for your string

Comment: `char userInput[1024] = "";` (*don't skimp on buffer size...*) 1K of stack space is cheap and protects against a cat stepping on the keyboard `:)` Also, you cannot consider any input "valid" unless you check the **return** of the input function, e.g. `if (scanf("%1023[^\n]", userInput) != 1) { fputs ("error: user canceled input or stream error.\n", stderr); return 1; }`

Comment: 100% agree with @DavidC.Rankin, specially if you have no idea of the size of the string.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will allocate memory for the appropriate size of the input. I haven't tested it, and it may need refinement to suit your requirement. I hope this helps.

```
char c;
int i = 0;
char *s = null;
do {
    c = getchar();
    s = (char *) realloc(s, i + 1); 
   if (c == 0x0a || c == 0x0c) { // test for 'Enter' key
        s[i] = null;
        break;
    }
    else {
        s[i++] = c;
    }
}
//... use s[] for whatever purpose ...
free(s);
```

Comment: damn that's smart. i will definitely use this for future coding. I do have one question though, I don't know if I heard it correctly from CS50 but I think using realloc multiple times is not efficient. please correct me if I am wrong and thanks for the code!

Comment: Only worry  about efficency if you can type really, really, really fast.